# How to upload files to FTP Server using Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ftp, azure-pipelines

**SITUATION**

I want to upload my release build as .zip file into my FTP Server

for this scenario let's assume that this is my environment.

> application type: **Console**
>
> folder I want to upload: **$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CompanyName.ProjectName.Console/bin/Release**
>
> my ftp server host: ftp://00.00.00.00:21/folderTest
>
> ftp username: **MyUsername**
>
> ftp password: **MyPassword**

for Azure agent: I allowed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/what-is-ip-address-168-63-129-16) (168.63.129.16) ip adress to be able to communicate with my ftp server

**azure pipelines**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CompanyName.ProjectName.Console/bin/Release
  artifact: CompanyName Project Name

- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'ftp://00.00.00.00:21'
    username: MyUsername
    password: MyPassword
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CompanyName.ProjectName.Console/bin/Release'
    remoteDirectory: '/folderTest'
    trustSSL: true
```

**PROBLEM**

following errors occur when I commit (for test purposes) something.

**##[error]Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 00.00.00.00:21 (control socket)**

**##[error]Ftp Upload failed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### [error]Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 00.00.00.00:21 (control socket)

I reproduced same issue and confirm this issue is more related to your FTP server.

Since you're using microsoft-hosted agent which is not in the same network as your VM where the FTP server exists, you should make sure your ftp server can be accessible from **external** network. Otherwise it's expected behavior to get error below:

[image]

We can easily create a ftp server which can be accessible by **internal** network. But to make it accessible from **external** network, we need to do more extra work. You may get useful info from this [issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-set-up-an-ftp-server-on-windows-10/ea5fd345-1137-49ba-b9fb-d04167dd6851).

(It's easy to find many related documents online about how to make local ftp server accessible from outside/external network or Internet, so I don't talk much about them here...)

**Here're two possible solutions:**

1.Install [self-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) agent in your VM where FTP server exists, then call the self-hosted agent instead of microsoft-hosted(`vmImage: 'windows-latest'`) agent to run your jobs. Since the self-agent is in same network like FTP server, so the build pipeline can succeed.

2.Configure your ftp server to make it accessible from external network.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply, I actually configured my FTP Server: I'm having issues with IP Adresses (I think). Can I say to my server to allow only 168.63129.16 to upload or do I have to make it public for everyone who knows FTP UserName and Password?

Comment: `Can I say to my server to allow only 168.63129.16 to upload or do I have to make it public for everyone who knows FTP UserName and Password?`  I'm afraid so, the ftp upload task need to enter a service connection. When creating the service connection we need to provide the Url, username, password, so we should make it public for everyone who knows FTP UserName and Password otherwise the service connection is meaningless, right? Hmm, and I'm bit confused about your ip, `00.00.00.00`, are you using this? This doesn't look like normal format...

Comment: as I described in my question: 00.00.00.00 is just a dummy value for my scenario, IRL I have a real host IP.  And about the first statement: no, I maybe want to "whitelist" only some IP addresses. Yet my actual question: Is MS agent's IP 168.63.129.16 or should I whitelist other MS IP there? Thanks in advance.